# How to "rearrange" a pandas data-frame using a map between columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to pandas and data-frames so I hope this is not a too basic question.

Suppose I have (outer) merged two data frames and obtained the following:

```
     date_a  symbol_a  value_a  type_a symbol_b  date_b  value_b  type_b    total
0    yymmdd    AAAA       10       W    AAAA     yymmdd     2        S        12
1    yymmdd    BBBB        5       W    BBBB     yymmdd     2        S         7
2    yymmdd    CCCC       12       W     NaN        NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN
3    yymmdd    DDDD       15       W     NaN        NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN
4     NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN   EEEE     yymmdd      5       S       NaN
5     NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN   FFFF     yymmdd     10       S       NaN
6     NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN   GGGG     yymmdd      2       S       NaN
```

this is so far quite what I want (the dates are all the same day).

Now suppose I have a rule that tells me that I have a mapping (dictionary):

```
mapper = {'EEEE':'CCCC', 'FFFF':'DDDD'}
```

I may have symbol_b that are not mapped to any symbol_a (like index 6 above).

My question is, is it possible to use re-arrange the rows according to the mapping given by the dictionary so to get:

```
     date_a  symbol_a  value_a  type_a symbol_b  date_b  value_b  type_b    total
0    yymmdd    AAAA       10       W    AAAA     yymmdd     2        S        12
1    yymmdd    BBBB        5       W    BBBB     yymmdd     2        S         7
2    yymmdd    CCCC       12       W    EEEE     yymmdd     5        S        17
3    yymmdd    DDDD       15       W    FFFF     yymmdd     10       S        25
6     NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN   GGGG     yymmdd      2       S       NaN
```

Ideally then I would also like to get rid of all the rows that contain a NaN element, so that the final result would be:

```
     date_a  symbol_a  value_a  type_a symbol_b  date_b  value_b  type_b    total
0    yymmdd    AAAA       10       W    AAAA     yymmdd     2        S        12
1    yymmdd    BBBB        5       W    BBBB     yymmdd     2        S         7
2    yymmdd    CCCC       12       W    EEEE     yymmdd     5        S        17
3    yymmdd    DDDD       15       W    FFFF     yymmdd     10       S        25
```

Comment: I think starting with original 2 dataframe is much easier

Comment: Can you explain how the mapping works? I'm not seeing it.

Comment: the column with _b merge with _a base on his provided dict, it means move from below to correct row as he merged it already

Comment: I agree with @PhungDuyPhong. Start with the originals, create an extra column to join the DFs based on the mapping, use an inner join and then .dropna()

Comment: Sorry maybe it wasn't clear. Basically I need the sum of the values of symbol_a and b. Some of them I can get automatically when I merge the data frames (because the symbols are the same) but some others not. However, I know how to associate which symbol_a to which symbol_b. The real thing is that symbol_a is a length 4 substring of symbol_b. When the latter 's length is <= 4 no problem but if it's longer I need to map them manually. Is it clearer this way? Consider index 2. Basically I'm saying that I would like to fill all the NaN on that row with the values at index 4 ( since CCCC->EEEE )

Comment: @Tommy we understand your desire clearly now, the question is, could we process the data before merge first, then merge then it will be automatically the thing you need, or you need us to provide a way to process on the df you already merged

Comment: So yeah I agree there might be a better way to start off with. Anyway even if I start off with the two original data frames, my question remains: how do I merge them according to the mapping?

Comment: @PhungDuyPhong thanks for your comments. To me is perfectly fine to start from the original ones and do it directly. I think it is easy to guess what these 2 original df are, should I edit the post? (I'm on mobile now and might be hard to do so for a while).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I split your dataframe to the original 2 dataframes, just change the name of columns in dataframe to fit your usage:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

#Split your merge df into 2 original df
del a['total']
df1 = a.loc[:, ['date_a', 'symbol_a', 'value_a', 'type_a']]
df2 = a.loc[:, ['date_b', 'symbol_b', 'value_b', 'type_b']]

df1.fillna('', inplace=True)
df2.fillna('', inplace=True)

df1 = df1[df1['date_a']!='']
df2 = df2[df2['date_b']!='']

#Add a mapping column to df2
mapper = {'EEEE':'CCCC', 'FFFF':'DDDD'}

df2['mapping'] = df2['symbol_b'].apply(lambda x: mapper.get(x) if mapper.get(x)!= None else x)

df1 = df1.merge(df2, left_on='symbol_a', right_on='mapping')
df1['total'] = df1['value_a'] + df1['value_b']
df1
```

The results in df1 is now:

```
    date_a  symbol_a    value_a type_a  date_b  symbol_b    value_b type_b  mapping total
0   yymmdd  AAAA        10.0    W       yymmdd  AAAA        2.0     S       AAAA    12.0
1   yymmdd  BBBB        5.0     W       yymmdd  BBBB        2.0     S       BBBB    7.0
2   yymmdd  CCCC        12.0    W       yymmdd  EEEE        5.0     S       CCCC    17.0
3   yymmdd  DDDD        15.0    W       yymmdd  FFFF        10.0    S       DDDD    25.0
```

Comment: for creating the `total` column: `df1['total'] = df1.apply(lambda x: x['value_a'] + x['value_b'], axis=1)` you should not need the `apply`. This should work as well `df1['total'] = df1['value_a'] + df1['value_b']`

Comment: @PhungDuyPhong Thanks, this seems to work fine. +1 for now let me check how actually things integrate and I will accept the answer later. One question, could you explain a little the line 'type(mapper.get('fdasf'))' ? Thank you again.

Comment: @Tommy I'm sorry it is not related, I just test the result to see what I receive when I get a key that does not exist